# Prove $||f^*||_p=||f||_p$ with $f^*(x)=f(-x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^p(R^n)$ and I want to prove that  $||f^*||_p=||f||_p$ with $f^*(x)=f(-x)$

$||f*||_p^p=\int_{R^n} |f^*(x)|^p dx=\int_{R^n}|f(-x)|^p dx$. Can I made achange of variable as $t=-x$?

Have I to distinguish case $1\le p\le \infty$ from $p=\infty$?

Comment: This looks OK to me. The only potential reason to distinguish the infinity case is that there, the norm is an essential sup norm and not defined by integration.

Comment: But $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, so don't you get a $-1^{n}$ factor from the change of variable. Your method still works out, but I think you should say why this factor goes away..